# Does the waterfall side of my table design have a strong joint?

Tags: joinery, wood

Is the waterfall side of my table design joined in a stable way to the top and frame? Plan is a hidden spline at the miter joint, and dowel to the frame. Shown as brown in the images linked. First ever furniture project.

[image: front and back view]
[image: top and side frame view]

The frame design doesn't show all dowels.

Answer (score 3):

Reasonably strong, however you will probably want to revise it to account for wood movement across the width of your oak leg. That 1x8 oak will account for a fair amount of expansion and contraction over time, and you have accounted for this in your top with the figure 8 fasteners, however for a structural leg as you show, you will have to get a little more creative.

You could probably route some horizontal slots in the stretcher at the end, and screw the leg into the stretcher through those slots. this way the top can expand and contract across the width, but will not move up or down against the table frame.

Comment: I really like the slot idea, actually. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Is there a reason you have the top attached to the sides of the waterfall side as opposed to having the top sit on top of the waterfall side thereby having the waterfall sides carry the weight instead of the dowels carrying the weight?

Comment: @Alaskaman, If your question is why I am using a miter joint rather than joining the waterfall and top at 90deg, then the answer is purely for aesthetic reasons only.

Comment: @Alaskaman  It's not a waterfall edge if it isn't mitered.